# How to address bugs in answers/comments that require significant evaluation

Tags: discussion

Suppose I'm watching a question, while doing some thinking and pondering an answer someone else comes up with a similar answer. I've no issues with that. But when that answer or comment make clearly-wrong statements as fact, how can I address them? In other words, even if the answer or comment is helpful, how do I address statements or coding remarks that are completely wrong (as in against the C++-spec kinda-wrong) when those issues have nothing to do with the original question?

For example: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326273/undefined-reference-to-a-derived-class/12326761#comment16544756_12326761) deals with a person's failure to get their configuration corrrectly for linking in object code. During the course of the q+a, someone makes a completely inaccurate statement about derived classes of base classes with pure virtual functions and/or virtual destructors being **required** to implement a destructor in the derived class. This is NOT true, but I could only post why it isn't in another answer (tried saying it in comment to no avail).

I don't think it is right of me to address that in an answer to the question (though I think the question author could probably learn a LOT from the post anyway), but is there some "correct" place to address this kind of thing?

THank you in advance. Cooler heads prevail. =P

Comment: That was what I was kinda of seeing as the general etiquette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's applicable, I don't see it as necessarily harmful. With that said, C++ isn't my strong point as it's been several years since I've worked with it, so I'm not 100% sure it applies to the question, but I'm not sure it doesn't either.

Your answer addresses points in another answer, but it's still helpful. It has an upvote, which means at least one other person found it helpful and it *is* an actual answer, as opposed to a follow up question or a comment posted as an answer.

I suggest being careful with this sort of thing. If a comment can address the problem on an answer, that is probably best. You can also downvote the answer. In some cases, you might even edit the answer and fix the problem if it's a quick fix.

You might find that if you do this too often, posting a looong comment as an answer, your answers may get downvoted, since the goal really isn't to address problems in other answers. My suggestion would be to edit your post and also find a way to address the error that the op is getting. That would not only make your post helpful but also dispel any doubt about whether some action needs to be taken on it, which is still a possibility. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for the considerations. I very much appreciate it.